# sql query returning too many results and replicants

Tags: mysql, sql

Title says it all. Im querying our data base and im getting replicants as well as too many results. It should be returning one part ID with one unit price.

```
    SELECT SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE, INVENTORY_TRANS.PART_ID, IT.QTY, CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE FROM INVENTORY_TRANS 
JOIN INVENTORY_TRANS IT ON INVENTORY_TRANS.PART_ID = IT.PART_ID
        AND INVENTORY_TRANS.TRANSACTION_ID = IT.TRANSACTION_ID
JOIN CUST_ORDER_LINE ON IT.CUST_ORDER_ID = CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID
        AND CUST_ORDER_LINE.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE = INVENTORY_TRANS.TRANSACTION_DATE
JOIN SHIPPER ON IT.CUST_ORDER_ID = SHIPPER.CUST_ORDER_ID
        AND CUST_ORDER_LINE.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE = SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE
        AND IT.TRANSACTION_DATE = SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE
WHERE SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE > '2016-05-01' AND SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE < '2016-06-01' 
ORDER BY IT.PART_ID
```

Comment: Why are you joining INVENTORY_TRANS back to itself?

Comment: quick answer: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`. but in reality *Title says it all* is not true at all. provide tables schema, some data for every table involved, describe result you expect to get, then somebody can help you to figure out what is wrong with your query.

Comment: we had a problem similar to this not to many months ago and thats what seemed to made it work. And im trying to sort the table by Parts shipped, how many were shipped and the price for the month of may.

Comment: SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE is 2016-05-18 00:00:00.000.
PART.ID is 01-51024-002
IT.QTY is 3.0000 and UNIT_PRICE is 47.000 

However im getting multiple different prices for each part number and in doing so its populating the table to over 8000 rows.

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: Its very large, our database is used with manufacturing software.

Comment: i can get a text version of the tables but as far as the schema its massive.

Comment: joining a table onto itself is a good way to get duplicates.  My bet is you have multiple copies of the same part id in the inventory_trans table.  Run this query: select count(*), part_id from inventory_trans group by part_id HAVING count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

I think your self-join INVENTORY_TRANS is not needed here. Cut it out and alias it with IT or something else in the from statement:

```
SELECT 
 SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE, 
 IT.PART_ID, 
 IT.QTY, 
 CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE 
FROM INVENTORY_TRANS IT
JOIN CUST_ORDER_LINE 
 ON (IT.CUST_ORDER_ID = CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID AND CUST_ORDER_LINE.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE = IT.TRANSACTION_DATE)
JOIN SHIPPER 
 ON (IT.CUST_ORDER_ID = SHIPPER.CUST_ORDER_ID AND CUST_ORDER_LINE.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE = SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE AND IT.TRANSACTION_DATE = SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE)
WHERE SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE > '2016-05-01' AND SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE < '2016-06-01' 
ORDER BY IT.PART_ID
```